# How can I attach a VHDx or VHD file in Linux?

Tags: linux, vhd

How can I attach a VHDX or VHD file in Linux?

I mean attach the virtual hard disk as a block device, and use external tools to read these devices.

The filesystem inside is not mountable. I do not need to mount the filesystem, but deal with it as if it was on a real hard disk.

I read the manual page of `guestfish`, but could not find how to do it.

Comment: Another ressource: 
https://www.how2shout.com/linux/mount-virtual-hard-disk-vhd-file-ubuntu-linux/?unapproved=516&moderation-hash=6ecfb4ca6f97ff53d32570f3ba2e28f0#comment-516

Answer (score 73):

You can use [`libguestfs-tools`](http://libguestfs.org/) to achieve this.

---

1. First, you need to install it, on Ubuntu/Debian-like Linux that would be:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install libguestfs-tools
   ```
2. Then, you can mount almost whatever you wish:

   ```
   guestmount --add yourVirtualDisk.vhdx --inspector --ro /mnt/anydirectory
   ```

   This is just an example of **read-only** extraction point.

---

Hints:

1. Run it as normal user, i.e.:

   ```
   guestmount ...
   ```

   Instead of:

   ```
   sudo guestmount ...
   ```
2. Switches; citations from [man page](http://libguestfs.org/guestmount.1.html):

   ```
   --add
   ```

   > Add a block device or virtual machine image.

   ```
   --inspector
   ```

   > Using [virt-inspector(1)](http://libguestfs.org/virt-inspector.1.html) code, inspect the disks looking for an operating system and mount filesystems as they would be mounted on the real virtual machine.

   ```
   --ro
   ```

   > Add devices and mount everything read-only. Also disallow writes and make the disk appear read-only to FUSE.

Comment: When the `vhd` file is too big (say 1TB with millions of files), `guestmount` could successfully mount it but fail in reading files (you can't even `ls -1f` to see the files). This must be an unsolved bug. Anyone who encounters this problem can try [qemu](https://askubuntu.com/a/359852/768041).

Comment: And `guestmount` (with no args at all) just segfaults on me (after newly installed here on a Raspbian Jessie).

Comment: Thanks for bringing up `guestmount` which I hoped would allow me to mount my .vhd containing a single partition with a exFAT-volume inside. Sadly, `guestmount` (v1.38.4) did not accept my specification of the volume within the `.vhd` and asking me `Did you mean to mount one of these filesystems?` ... `/dev/sda1 (exfat)`. What I had specified was `-m "/dev/sda1"` as this was what `virt-filesystems` had returned. When the volume is NTFS, mounting works. And yes, I've got `exfat-utils.x86_64` (v1.2.8, a fuse-fs-driver) installed.

Comment: I can confirm this works for VHD(x) images downloaded from Azure VMs.

Comment: If anyone is trying to do this on Windows via WSL, this web page has the additional info you need to complete the task: https://blog.codybunch.com/2020/10/16/WSL2-Mount-vhdx-to-WSL2/